# ! Failed to install gems via Bundler Heroku Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm super new to RoR and am attempting to deploy my app on heroku. I'm getting the error you can see in the title.

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.0'
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.3'
gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Stack**

```
Enumerating objects: 424, done.
Counting objects: 100% (424/424), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (391/391), done.
Writing objects: 100% (424/424), 265.61 KiB | 6.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 424 (delta 193), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.16
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.16
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Unable to find a spec satisfying nokogiri (>= 1.8.5) in the set. Perhaps the
remote:        lockfile is corrupted? Found nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri
remote:        (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri
remote:        (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin) that did not match the
remote:        current platform.
remote:        Bundler Output: Unable to find a spec satisfying nokogiri (>= 1.8.5) in the set. Perhaps the
remote:        lockfile is corrupted? Found nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri
remote:        (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri
remote:        (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin), nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin) that did not match the
remote:        current platform.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

I have gone through every previous question on here and tried all the solutions.
I have already tried to delete the gemfile.lock and run bundle install again to reset it. I have done various git add, commits and pushes. I'm kind of at a loss of where to go from here. Any advice would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin)` is native gem for `Darwin/MacOS`, but Heroku run `Linux` so that it `unable to find`.

the solution is [avoid-using-a-precompiled-native-gem](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#how-can-i-avoid-using-a-precompiled-native-gem), in your case, `bundler` version 2.2.+, then you'll need to run `bundle config set force_ruby_platform true`

you should re-check that `Gemfile.lock` does not contain `nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-darwin)`, it should contain `nokogiri (~> ...)`

Comment: Thank you Lam, I ran your command and checked the gemfile.lock for the nokogiri Gem and it is not present. Unfortunately i still cannot deploy to Heroku

Comment: Yes, Still the same. I ended up adding gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.11.7" to my gemfile and running bundle. This fixed ther problem! Thanks for your help Lam!

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue on the M1 Macbook. I deleted the `Gemfile.lock`, then ran bundle install to re-build the `Gemfile.lock` and this fixed the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Running `bundle update nokogiri` updated only the Nokogiri gem dependencies for me without updating the rest of the Gemfile